# Is there R function that can connect different sunrise/sunset hours, creating a line for the sunrise and other for the sunset hours?

Tags: r, heatmap, linechart

I have a heatmap with specific information for each hour of the day, and then I have the info for sunrise and sunset hours for each day of my timeline.

Right now, I have the "mini" lines for the sunrise and sunset, but sunrise line and sunset line connecting all the "mini" lines, is it possible?

This is my code for the heatmap plus the sunrise/sunset lines:

```r
heatmap_plot <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Hour, y = interaction_order, fill = presence)) +
  geom_tile(size = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = custom_palette, na.value = "grey") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Hour", y = "Day") +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(df$Hour)) +
  geom_line(data = line_data, aes(x = Sunrise_hour, y = interaction_order),linetype = "solid", color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_line(data = line_data, aes(x = Sunset_hour, y = interaction_order), linetype = "solid", color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = line_data, aes(x = Sunrise_hour, y = interaction_order), color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = line_data, aes(x = Sunset_hour, y = interaction_order), color = "black", size = 1)
print(heatmap_plot)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: something with `geom_contour()` ?